# Zip Pipeline Utility - Recursively Zip Sub Dir and Files

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

Can I use this [utility](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#zip-create-zip-file) to recursively zip files and sub-dirs under a dir?

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the documentation , if I do not set value for "glob" , all the files and dirs are getting included as part of the zip file.